# Steps to implement - One to One Video call App using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

Can Anyone please let me know how we can do a one to one video calling app using twilio.

I could get some sample codes to do a group video chat, but my requirement is particular to have it one to one, please guide if there is any way to do it using twilio.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, make sure that you read both [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before asking any question.

Answer (score 1):

To build a one to one video calling app, you can follow the same steps to build a multiparty group chat, but limit the access to the room to only 2 participants.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build a video calling app with the help of Twilio WebRTC Go, and WebRTC Go rooms have default max participants set at 2.

To know more about how to set "max participants" with Twilio WebRTC you can visit the link [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/announcing-twilio-video-webrtc-go).

To understand more about different type of Video rooms using Twilio, you can also visit this [doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#video-webrtc-go-rooms).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the room limit to 2, when making the multi-party video app using Video Room. Second option is to use WebRTC as mention above, [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-free-one-on-one-video-chat-webrtc-go-javascript) is the guide of making such app using NodeJS by twilio.